# Pseudo element throwing syntax error in VS code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, visual-studio-code, styled-components

I’m using styled component for my application and would need to use a pseudo class for doing some styling in a particular scenario. 
But in VS code its showing syntax error even its working properly in browser. Attached the screen shot.

[image: VS code syntax error]

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance
Shah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your code as below

```
export const Element = styled.div`
 /* your styles */
 ${InnerElement}{
   &:only-child {    
       /* your style */
   }
 }
`
```

Comment: Thank you @rEjITh. It really saved my time.